# arrange values in a python 2D array

Tags: python

I'm new to python and I'm having a problem that I'm not able to solve.

I have the following 2D array:

```
valuearray = [['A', '21', '45'], ['A', '12', '23'], 
              ['A', '54', '21'], ['A', '15', '54'], 
              ['B', '23', '53'], ['B', '34', '53'], 
              ['B', '32', '54'], ['B', '24', '13'], 
              ['C', '31', '43'], ['C', '42', '54'], 
              ['C', '35', '54'], ['C', '12', '11']]

A  21 45
A  12 23
A  54 21
A  15 54
B  23 53
B  34 53
B  32 54
B  24 13
C  31 43
C  42 54
C  35 54
C  12 11
```

I need to generate from this array another array that have the unique values of `valuearray[0]` , the maximum of `valuearray[1`] for each `valuearray[0]`  and the minimum `valuearray[2]` for each `valuearray[0]`

The result would be:

```
resarray[]

    A  54 21
    B  34 13
    C  42 11
```

***EDIT: sorry for not presenting what I tried***

```
    uniquenames = []
    un = []
    for i in range(len(valuearray)):
            un.append(valuearray[i][0])
    uniquenames=uniq(un)

test = []
for ci in range(len(valuearray)):
    for gn in range(len(uniquenames)):
        if(valuearray[ci][0] == uniquenames[gn]):
                      # i don't know what to do here
                      i tried append(valuearray[ci][0] , max(valuearray[ci][1]),min( valuearray[ci][2]))
```

but append only take one parametre, so I don't know how to continue.

And uniq is a function that gives me the unique values from a list.

Comment: Fascinating. What have you tried?

Comment: Downvoting. Make an effort besides just transcribing your homework.

Comment: Are all A's, B's, and C's grouped together and arranged in order?

Comment: Also, try to represent your arrays in the format they are in Python.

Comment: yes, i used the `sorted` function to arrange them ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do this pretty easily with [`itertools.groupby`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) and [`zip()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip):

```
data = [
    ['A', '21', '45'],
    ['A', '12', '23'],
    ['A', '54', '21'],
    ['A', '15', '54'],
    ['B', '23', '53'],
    ['B', '34', '53'],
    ['B', '32', '54'],
    ['B', '24', '13'],
    ['C', '31', '43'],
    ['C', '42', '54'],
    ['C', '35', '54'],
    ['C', '12', '11']
]

from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

for name, values in groupby(data, itemgetter(0)):
    _, first, second = zip(*values)
    print(name, max(first), min(second))
```

What we are doing here is using `groupby()` to group the list items by the first item. This gives us three lists - a list for the records beginning with A, then a list for B, then C. It's also worth noting that `groupby()` doesn't require your list to be sorted.

We then extract the values from these lists by using `zip()` to unzip the values from a list of triplets into three lists of single values. We throw away the first column as it's just A, B or C as is relevant, and then take the maximum and minimum of the other columns to get the values you wanted.

Which gives us:

```
A 54 21
B 34 13
C 42 11
```

## Edit:

If you have your values as text, then you can use a [list comprehension](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t85uBptTDYY) and [`str.split()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) to make a list out of it:

```
data = """\
A  21 45
A  12 23
A  54 21
A  15 54
B  23 53
B  34 53
B  32 54
B  24 13
C  31 43
C  42 54
C  35 54
C  12 11\
"""

data = [value.split() for value in data.split("\n")]
```

## Another Edit:

As per the chat, you can discard extra columns like so:

Python 3.x:

```
for name, values in groupby(data, itemgetter(0)):
    _, first, second, *_ = zip(*values)
    print(name, max(first), min(second))
```

Python 2.x:

```
for name, values in groupby(data, itemgetter(0)):
    first, second = zip(*values)[1:3]
    print name, max(first), min(second)
```

## And to make the output a list, rather than printing the values:

```
def max_min_by_group(group):
    for name, values in group:
        _, first, second, *_ = zip(*values)
        yield [name, max(first), min(second)]

new = [item for item in max_min_by_group(groupby(data, itemgetter(0)))]
```

We simply use a list comprehension and a generator (we could do this in one big line but it would be unwieldy and unreadable). This gives us:

```
[['A', '54', '21'], ['B', '34', '13'], ['C', '42', '11']]
```

Comment: @ifreak As you said 'I have a 2D array', I presumed you had a list of lists.

Comment: yes, but this will woek in case i had to add other columns to the array ?? or other rows ??

Comment: @ifreak: If you read it, you can clearly see this will work if you add more rows, however, it would not work with more columns - you did not mention it needing to work with more columns, and did not say how you wanted more columns to act if they were added.

Comment: basically i've got the list from a text file, but i might need to add columns to the file and then do this method, in this case how should i act(update the code) to make it more dynamic ???

Comment: @ifreak You are not being very clear. What do you want new columns to do? What do you mean by 'more dynamic'?

Comment: i mean is there any way to perform this task even if i added more columns, because in this case i only can do it if i have 3 columns.. but i need something that will not be affected if i added more columns, or even more rows with (e.g D,E,F, ....etc)

Comment: As I said, this will work with any number of rows. As to more columns, you need to tell me what you want it to do with more columns. You get the maximum of the first column and the minimum of the second, but what would you do with the third? Not to mention changing this to support more columns is entirely trivial.

Comment: it has to do the same arrangement but with more columns .. 10 columns for example

Comment: @ifreak The same? As in max, min every 2 columns? Please be clear. What should happen if there are an odd number of columns? Either way, these changes are pretty trivial, have you tried changing it yourself?

Comment: yes i did, but eventually i end up doing it in another way, using 2 for loops. so i think the topic should be closed. is it important to post my solution??

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10698/discussion-between-ifreak-and-lattyware)